# Android Studio: Hide Navigation bar?

Tags: android-studio, design-view

Is there a way to hide the Navigation bar (back, home settings etc..) in Design View? --- essentially showing my app full screen (except for the pull down action bar)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Show and hide ActionBar with AppCompat v.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284627/how-to-show-and-hide-actionbar-with-appcompat-v-7)

Comment: What exactly did you want?

Answer (score 1):

is to late but this answer maybe can help someone 
add this to your activity

```
    @Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not answering the question. He wanted to hide the navigation in the design preview..