# How To Show and hide ActionBar with AppCompat v.7

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have a simple app that displays text.

The app starts with a main screen with a few options (ex. an info button that leads to info about the app, a browse button that allows the user to see all the individual pieces of text that can be displayed).  The main button leads to another screen where text is displayed.  By swiping left and right he can see different passages of text.  This is the main purpose of the app.

Currently I have an ActionBar implemented.  My MainActivity.Java extends AppCompatActivity.  Everything in the app is in this activity.

Now I want to make it so the ActionBar appears only in "Display" mode, not in the start up screen, or "info" / "browse" mode.

**Is it possible to have an ActionBar in one part of the app, and *no* ActionBar in another part of the app? (And keep it all in the same activity?)**

I've been trying to accomplish this without avail.  If this is possible, what should I try next?

So far, I've attempted the following:

1)  Create this theme

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>  
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And apply it to MainActivity ...

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >
```

....
After doing this, the ActionBar was still there.  (This comes from this S.O. post ([android:windowNoTitle will not hide actionbar with appcompat-v7 21.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26878386))

2)  Another attempt was to add this to onCreate.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getActionBar().hide();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

This came from studying this S.O. post:  ([How to hide action bar before activity is created, and then show it again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500283))

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

In the activities **where you want to have *no* action bar** use a theme derived from  `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` or `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`. This activity will never be able to show the action bar unless you supply your own via `setSupportActionBar(Toolbar)`.

In the activities **where you want to have the action bar** use a theme derived from `Theme.AppCompat`, `Theme.AppCompat.Light` or `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`. This will allow you to dynamically hide or show the action bar in such activity. You will not be able to supply your own action bar using these themes.

When **working with appcompat-v7 action bar** you need to obtain it by calling `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`.

Answer (score 59):

You can hide and show  the ActionBar programatically.

To hide

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

To Show

```
getSupportActionBar().show();
```

It can also be done **from Fragments**

To hide

```
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

To Show

```
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().show();
```

Edit:

As noted by [@RenniePet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/253938/renniepet),

You need to call `((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()`, if you're using `Toolbar` as the `ActionBar`.

Comment: For use in a fragment I had to do this: "((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();"

Comment: `hide()` will throw a null exception.

Answer (score 12):

Extend you activity as `AppCompatActivity` and then use action bar as:-

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();  // for hiding
getSupportActionBar().show();  // for showing
```

Comment: As a note, `ActionBarActivity` is now deprecated. `AppCompatActivity` should be used instead

Comment: The `hide` call has no effect in my app.

Answer (score 5):

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>  
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

remove android in item windowActionbar.just like follow:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>  
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: need to remove android from android:windowNoTitle too.

Answer (score 3):

*AppCompatActivity* has its own embedded toolbar. You dont need to use extra toolbar definition in your main xml.

just call **getSupportActionBar().show()**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().show();
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

        TextView text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        text1.setText("I changed the text!");

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In onCreate method, after setContentView, use this simply to show or hide for each class.

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
getSupportActionBar().show();
```

If you want to set title,

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("This is ToolBar");
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can be solution. It worked on my system:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: This forces use of obsolete theme and does not cover appcompat.

Answer (score 0):

Dismiss ToolBar for all activities with `AppTheme`:
**styles.xml**:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"><!-- .NoActionBar -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to show/hide the ActionBar of an INTENT with AppCompatActivity and you get the following issues:

- pointer null exception ...
- thread issue ...

Follow these steps to access to the same relevant thread into the intent:

```
// 1) Calling the intent in the "main activity"
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourClass.class);
startActivity(intent);

// 2) Get the context in your "Intent activity"
public class YourClass extends AppCompatActivity {
YourClass mContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mContext = this;
}

// 3) Hide/Show Action bar from a method
public void yourMethod(YourClass mContext){

    mContext.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mContext.getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }
    });

}
```