# Toolbar overlapping fragment into appcompactActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, toolbar

When i click fragment to activity than tool bar is overlapping see below **Image**:

[image]

How can we remove the fragment toolbar at runtime? I already use `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` property but nothing change.

Comment: Have you use getSupportActionbar.hide() function?

Comment: yes i use getSupportActionbar.hide() hide the tool bar but activity not display in full screen @MohitSuthar

Comment: @FinavaVipul you need to change your default theme http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284769/1765530

Comment: Thanks @appukrb finally i have solution add theme in manifests file with particular activity

Answer (score 0):

add this line in manifests file `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"`