# Android Hide actionbar and Toolbar

Tags: android

in manifest i use

```
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 23
```

and now, i want to hide theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ir.pishguy.simpleadvancepagedesign">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>


<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

but i get this error:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a 
Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this:

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">`

with this:

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`

and if you want to hide the toolbar after the `setSupportActionbar(Toolbar toolBar)` method use `getSupportActionbar().hide();`

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 2):

Use `getSupportActionBar().hide();` in activity.

Or `getActivity.getSupportActionBar().hide();` in fragment .

Answer (score 1):

Check my solution at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284751/2715073)

OR

Use style

```
<style name="FullScreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- ... -->
</style>
```