# How do I modify/get rid of this bar at the top of my listview?

Tags: android, xml, listview

Just like the title says I'm trying to get rid of this bar and I could find no reference to it anywhere in my xml or code. I was looking around on this website also and could not find a suggestion that worked. I mean the blue area that says listview on it. Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWUWG.jpg

Comment: Why do you want to remove the Toolbar?

Comment: Do you mean the scrollbar?

Comment: `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme

Comment: I just want to know how I'm not sure if I will. That's why I also included modify in my title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Full Screen Theme for AppCompat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653305/full-screen-theme-for-appcompat) or if not full screen then [how to hide action bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284627/how-to-show-and-hide-actionbar-with-appcompat-v-7)

Comment: @TimCastelijns " I mean the blue area that says listview on it." I think he means the titlebar.

Comment: You appear to be referring to [the action bar](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html). The *vast* majority of Android apps use the action bar, as it provides common context to the user to know what app they are in, where to perform common actions, and so forth. As cricket_007 mentions, you can remove it, but *please know exactly why you are removing it*.

Answer (score 0):

You can take away it in your Activity like this

```
 onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 // use this before you create a view
 ActionBar actionBar = getSupportedActionBar();
 if(actionBar != null){
     actionBar.hide();
 }

 setContentView(R.layout.some_layout);
 ...
 }
```