# White bar on using no action bar android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

i have main activity and using this style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

**but this still showing action bar on nexus 5 devices**
[image]

Comment: post your xml code

Comment: check out this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284627/how-to-show-and-hide-actionbar-with-appcompat-v-7  May be it will help you.

Comment: its simple Relative layout with frame layout which used to hold fragment @Amir_P

Comment: @Usman Saeed try my answer

Comment: Post your layout XML.

Answer (score 4):

If all the rest doesn't work for you, make sure You don't have this in your XML:

```
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Answer (score 1):

add this into your activity source code at the first of your public class

```
getActionbar().hide();
```