# Got an error for removing an app title

Tags: android

I want to get rid of the app title bar so i add these codes:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Instead i got an error with this:

```
03-05 16:30:48.735 10016-10016 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

What is wrong with getting an app title bar removed?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284627/how-to-show-and-hide-actionbar-with-appcompat-v-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message states, your theme needs to be `Theme.AppCompat` or decent of `Theme.AppCompat`.

That means you need a theme with its parent as `Theme.AppCompat` or theme with inherits it.

Add this to your `styles.xml`.

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

And in the manifest, change your activity theme to this theme.

```
<activity
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
```

Comment: i got 3 errors instead. Cant build apk because of this error:

Comment: Error:UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3

Comment: Try doing `Invalidate cache and restart` in the file menu.

Answer (score -1):

your activity extend AppCompatAcctity not Activity