# Unable to hide deafault action bar [ANDROID]

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I am creating an android app, i am trying to hide default action bar and us my own custom toolbar as action bar but the problem is that default navigation icon and title of action bar are not being hidden and when i open navigation drawer from right side my custom navigation icon from left side hides and android's default navigation icon is displayed instead.
i have tried using NoActionBar and NoTheme styles too but its not working.
Here is a sample of my code, where i am going wrong

Any help will be appreciated.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    Toolbar main_toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        setUpToolBar();
    }

    public void setUpToolBar() 
    {
        main_toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        //set up the home_main_toolbar
        android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        setSupportActionBar(main_toolbar);
        if (activity.getSupportActionBar() != null)
            main_toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.img_toolbar);
        main_toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               //Open navigation drawer
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: try getSupportActionBar().hide();

Comment: @kggoh before setting toolbar?

Comment: @User i think doesnt matter, .hide only hide it, the action bar is still exist, it just you can't see it. but you need to make sure getSupportActionBar() is not null

Comment: Do this by menifest
   <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

use this code in your android menifest , surely it will work

Comment: its not working, the default navigation icon or action bar still appears

Comment: its not working, the default navigation icon on action bar still appears

Comment: use this link for further ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284627/how-to-show-and-hide-actionbar-with-appcompat-v-7

Answer (score 2):

try it in manifest where your activity is defined.

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to Styles.xml

add this style there

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

and use it in manifest

```
   <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```