# How to hide action Bar in android once SoftKeyboard shows up

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have seen [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284627/how-to-show-and-hide-actionbar-with-appcompat-v-7).

My `androidManifest.xml` file contains: `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar" >`

In one of my fragments, i need to call the soft keyboard. As soon as I call the soft keyboard, the action bar appears as well, and is never hidden after that. In that fragment, I have:

```
view.setOnClickListener {
            val imm = context?.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager?
            imm?.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0)

            (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.hide()

        }
```

I expect this to hide the keyboard if a part of the fragment besides the input area was tapped (which it does), and also hide the action bar (it does not).

In this fragment, there is a button. On click, a new fragment is loaded. In that newly Loaded fragment's `onCreateView` I have:

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.hide()
```

In the same fragment's `onResume` I have:

```
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).actionBar?.hide()
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.hide()

    }
```

But the action bar persists.

My android SDKs are as follows:

```
ANDROID_MIN_SDK_VERSION=23
ANDROID_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=33
ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION=33
KOTLIN_VERSION = 1.6.10
```

**Question:**

How can I force the action bar to stay hidden, even if the Soft keyboard is called?Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe this method will solve your problem. It basically listens the keyboard visibility and hides action bar if its visible as you see below. Call it on your activity

```
fun hideActionBarIfKeyboardVisible() {
     ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(window.decorView) { view, insets ->
         val imeVisible = insets.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
         
         if(imeVisible){
             supportActionBar?.hide()
         }
         
         ViewCompat.onApplyWindowInsets(view, insets)
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hence i call it in my main activity - and not on the fragment? Also, where in the activity exactly? in onResume?

Comment: onCreate should do the job, I said call in activity, because you requested to hide action bar every time keyboard visible. So it has to be managed from activity to be able to work on every fragment.

Comment: @ Burak Unfortunately, the solution does not work

Comment: How did the solution behave?

Comment: no effect at all